# Using a std::promise with thread with member function error C2664

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

I am getting an error saying

> ```
>  error C2664: 
> 'void std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall WalkingController::*
> )(std::promise<std::tuple<float,float>>
> &&),void,WalkingController,std::promise<std::tuple<float,float>>
> &&>::operator ()(_Farg0 &,std::promise<std::tuple<float,float>> &&)
> const' : cannot convert argument 2 from
> 'std::promise<std::tuple<float,float>>' to
> 'std::promise<std::tuple<float,float>> &&'
> ```

I am trying to create a promise that will run on a separate thread to execute a member function in my class.
It looks like this:

```
std::promise<std::tuple<float, float>> p_upperTorques;
auto f_upperTorques = p_upperTorques.get_future();
std::thread t1(&WalkingController::CalculateTorqueForUpperLegs, this, std::move(p_upperTorques));
t1.join();
...std::get<0>(f_upperTorques.get()), std::get<1(f_upperTorques.get())...
```

The function I am calling is

```
void WalkingController::CalculateTorqueForUpperLegs(std::promise<std::tuple<float, float>> &&p) {
...
p.set_value(std::make_tuple(ullTorque, urlTorque));
}
```

Whats the correct way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Msvc has a bug.  Sorry mate.  Try passing something like a shared ptr to a promise?

Comment: Why are you passing by rvalue reference into `CalculateTorqueForUpperLegs`? That conveys that you would like to move the argument into something else inside the function (and allows it).  I'm not an expert on `std::thread` implementations, but I would kind-of expect it to keep a copy (or a moved object) of `args` and then pass them to `f`. Such an implementation would not be able to bind the lvalue to the rvalue reference when calling `CalculateTorqueForUpperLegs`. Try changing the parameter type to `CalculateTorqueForUpperLegs` to an lvalue reference.

Comment: So to answer myself, I was totally wrong and @Yakk is correct that this is a bug with your compiler's lib implementation. `std::thread` is defined to pass the `args` as a decayed copy of the thread's storage, which is an rvalue.